# css styles not working when applied to table cell

Tags: css, html, css-tables

I have applied a width of 100% to all the `td` in the table but only the first td of the row gets a width of 100%. while the other `td` collapses.

```css
table, th, td {
        border: 1px solid black;
        width: 100%;
    }
```

```html
<table>
      <tr>
        <th>Month</th>
        <th>Savings</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>$100</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>February</td>
        <td>$80</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    
    <p><b>Note:</b> The width attribute is not supported in HTML5. Use CSS instead.</p>
```

Comment: you should add width:100% on table. and also add width in percentage of all td as per you want

Answer (score 0):

this style block should be like:

```
<style>
table{
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 100%;
}
th, td {
border: 1px solid black;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

This snippet will demonstrate how table widht works

```css
table{
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 100%;
}

td:nth-child(1),th:nth-child(1){
    width: 70%
}

td:nth-child(2),th:nth-child(2){
    width: 30%
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
</style>
</head>
<body>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Month</th>
    <th>Savings</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>January</td>
    <td>$100</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>February</td>
    <td>$80</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

You need to specify a relative width for the columns.

If your table is 100% width it will take the full width of the container (a div, the body)

The columns will have to fit in this width and the sum of their width must be no more than 100% (the width . If you want three columns for example you can assign a width to two of them and the third will fit in the remain space. 
First column 20%, second column 30%. The third one will fit the remaining 50%.

The nth-child pseudo selector allows you to determine a specific css formatting for each column (the number in brakets is the index of the column). So in the example I have set the width of the first column as 70% of the full table and the second 30% (I could omit it since it woudl fit anyway the full width of the table)

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <style type="text/css">
    table, th, td {
        border: 1px solid black;
    }
    table{
      width: 100%;
      text-align: center;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>

  <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Month</th>
        <th>Savings</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>$100</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>February</td>
        <td>$80</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Will depend on how the table is rendered.
The table itself have a certain width, and the cell will take a fixed or relative witdh (depending of the unit used, fixed/relative, as e.g. pixels vs percentages). When rendering the first td it takes the choosen width, 100%, and when it is going to render the second cell... there is no space to assign another 100% of width.
If the desired result is a table with colums having the same width you can get it adding table-layout: fixed; (and there are more solutions)

Search about "table rendering model" if you want to know more about all this stuff. Tables can be really tricky (evil and fun).

```css
table{
        border: 1px solid black;
        width: 100%;/*this is the width of the table, as % of the 'available width' on the container*/
        table-layout: fixed;
    }
  td {
        border: 1px solid black;
        width: 55%;/*does not really matters the ammount, as it is the same for all columns and its sum is 100% or more*/
    }
```

```html
<table>
      <tr>
        <th>Month</th>
        <th>Savings</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>$100</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>February</td>
        <td>$80</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    
    <p><b>Note:</b> The width attribute is not supported in HTML5. Use CSS instead.</p>
```